# How to use SpanX in bootstrap in web?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have used span4(using bootstrap css) in my code But it was not any effect in design.
So, Please  what is wrong in my code and any reference is reaming to add ?
Here My code,

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">  
    <link href="bootstrap-3.1.1-dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="bootstrap-3.1.1-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="bootstrap-3.1.1-dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>  
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<div class="container">  
<div class="row">  
  <div class="span4"><p>Col1.</p></div>  
  <div class="span4"><p>Col2.</p></div> 
<div class="span4"><p>Col3.</p></div> 
</div>    
</div>
```

Output:
 Col1

col2

Col3

But I want to output Like Col1 Col2 Col3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap 3 uses `col-*` instead of `span*`..

```
<div class="container">  
  <div class="row">  
    <div class="col-md-4"><p>Col1.</p></div>  
    <div class="col-md-4"><p>Col2.</p></div> 
    <div class="col-md-4"><p>Col3.</p></div> 
  </div>    
</div>
```

http://bootply.com/126717

Also see: [Whats new in Bootstrap 3](http://www.bootply.com/bootstrap-3-migration-guide)